# Debouncing circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I have a system where I want to place to simple push button switches at the end of a 12inch cable.  Is it better to place the debouncing circuit with the buttons or with the microprocessor, 12" from the buttons?

If it matters the debouncing circuit is based on a Maxim 812R (https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1858) and the microprocessor is a Wemos D1, the buttons are generic NC push button switches.

Comment: upvoted because I dislike people down-voting a question that's a fair question. Whatever happened to "there is no stupid question"? At least leave a comment if you think it's a bad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend placing debouncing circuit on main PCB close to the microcontroller,  for two reasons:

1. Cable itself have some capacitance which can improve debouncing.
2. Placing debouncing  circuit close to the micro can perhaps filter some potential electromagnetic interference inducted in the cable.

Also the pull-up resistor should be placed on the main board close to the point where cable is connected.